# The keyword export in command line?

Tags: bash, msys

What does 'export' do when used in a command line.
For example, and this is only one example, I build a number of C++ libraries and for a library such as zlib-1.2.8 I need to specify the install directories.

To do this I need to do the following in MSYS command line interface. This is just one example

```
export LIBRARY_PATH="c/libraries/libs;$LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Would anyone know what the command 'export' actually does in this instance?
Does it permanently install a record for MSYS to user later on when looking for dependencies such as ZLIB .  My using make install the zlib library file is placed in this directory.

OR, when I close MSYS is this LIBRARY_PATH lost from MSYS memory?

Thanks

Comment: To add to the answer below, `export` in bash is similar to `SET` in batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the bash syntax to [set an environment variable](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html).  Using `export` allows the variable to be seen outside the script in which it's defined.

Environment variables only affect the msys process and any child processes started from that shell.  If you want it to persist after you close the command line and start a new one, you will need to put it into a script such as `.bashrc`